# how should i add a textfield/button to a table view controller?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a UITableViewController with a nav bar up top from an embedded nav controller. In between the nav bar and the start of the cells I'm trying to add a textfield and button sort of like a search bar layout but for a different purpose.

On my storyboard, I can drag in a button or a label, but it automatically fills the width of the scene. As a result there is only room for one or the other. I tried editing with the size inspector in the right pane but it reverts to the old number everytime.

How would I pull this layout off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view with the label/text field and the button then drag the view to the top of the tableview. It will add the view as a header view.

Comment: i essentially did what you suggested except in the object library there's a specific thing just called 'view' and I used that

Comment: yep. i was just commenting because how i did it was sort of different, but essentially the same idea.